# Can you use the weierstrass approximation theorem to show the convergence of fourier series to its function?

Tags: fourier-series, weierstrass-approximation

I was wondering if it is possible to show that the fourier series expansion of a function is equal to its function by using a proof similiar to the weierstrass approximation theorem.

Comment: For what functions and  convergence in what sense ? It is not true that Fourier series of a continuous function converges to it piontwise.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "equal" and "convergence"